# Version 1.5.0_30 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. 1.6 or greater is required OSX

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, osx-leopard

I recently downloaded eclipse for RCP and RAP developers. I am running OSX 10.5.8, and when I tried running eclipse i got the error "Version 1.5.0_30 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. 1.6 or greater is required". I went to utilities then java preferences and made sure that Java SE 6 was at the top of the preferred order list, it was not so I moved it up. I verified my system was pointing to the correct version

```
user-Macbook-Pro:~ user$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-9M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)
```

however i still get the same error when trying to open eclipse. Any suggestions? Thank you for the help

Comment: which version your JAVA_HOME is pointing to? Do you have multiple versions?

Comment: "echo $JAVA_HOME" returns an empty line, 

"ls /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/" returns 1.3  1.4.2  1.6  Current
1.3.1  1.5  1.6.0  CurrentJDK
1.4  1.5.0  A

so I have multiple versions, but apparently JAVA_HOME isn't pointing to any of them...

Answer (score 1):

It starts working after I modified eclipse.ini like below and added

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```